# Problem booting Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: xubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 alongside with Windows 
And it worked correctly  I switched graphic driver to nvidia 
And completed some work and restarted my laptop.

When the laptop turned on i received a message saying:

> a tpm error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value

When I'm trying to log in Ubuntu  I receive only black screen.

My Laptop is  elite book 8440p

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use liveCD or liveUSB Ubuntu.

Open terminal from liveCD, and

1. determine which disk and on which partition Ubuntu is installed

`sudo fdisk -l`

2. For work we need the / -section (root). mount it with a command

`sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt`

where `sdaX` - number partition Ubuntu

3. continue to use the answer [A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851975/a-tpm-error-7-occurred-attempting-to-read-a-pcr-value) changing the command

`echo "blacklist tpm_tis" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/tpm_tis.conf`

on

`echo "blacklist tpm_tis" | sudo tee -a /mnt/etc/modprobe.d/tpm_tis.conf`