# Failing Installation of Ubuntu 18.04 w/ Lenovo Thinkpad P73 cannot boot up saying: "[Firmware bug]: TPM interrupt not working"

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, lenovo, thinkpad, firmware

I persistently get [this bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204121).

Installed **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** on a **Thinkpad p73**.

---

#### However...

It doesn't do *anything* beyond that unless I do a hard-shutdown.

---

#### So what I tried is...

After hard-shutdown it boots into a login, but after typing my password and hitting Return/Enter it remains a purple background with mouse cursor that cannot be moved around.

---

## Question

Has anybody had any luck, e.g. set an alternative bootup flag/option to make it work for them?

---

**EDIT (sorry for delays)**:

Many thanks, to [WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix) the firmware bug is now gone (after switching off TPM from BIOS as you kindly advised) however there is another bug that spawned which goes as such:

`Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[   ***] (2 of 2) A start job is running for Wait until snapd is fully seeded (21s / no limit) 
VFS: busy inodes on changed media or resized disk sda`

**[EDIT 2:]**

Shout outs to [Oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred), since I am now trying to get my wifi card to work. And he is on to something +1.

Comment: Do you have the latest UEFI from Lenovo for that system?

Comment: Thanks @oldfred, it must be since the laptop literally arrived fresh out the OEM box 2 days ago, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. I would at least check your version & latest available.  It could have been manufactured several months ago & update to UEFI more recent.

Comment: New Lenovo now can update UEFI directly from Linux. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/ (shows your P73). & https://fwupd.org/lvfs/docs/users You typically have to reboot after update & may have to redo some UEFI settings as they revert to defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this Q&A:

- [A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851975/a-tpm-error-7-occurred-attempting-to-read-a-pcr-value)

A number of solutions are provided:

- Turn off TPM in your BIOS.
- Tell Ubuntu to ignore TPM:

  `echo "blacklist tpm_tis" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/tpm_tis.conf`

Comment: Many thanks, the firmware bug is now gone (after switching off TPM from BIOS as you kindly advised) however there is another bug that spawned which goes as such:

`Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[   ***] (2 of 2) A start job is running for Wait until snapd is fully seeded (21s / no limit) 
VFS: busy inodes on changed media or resized disk sda`

Comment: Okay, upon second reboot, the BIOS, threw me a Blue Screen and asked me to "MOK Enroll" the hard drives using a password. Then rebooting again fixed it. 

I am not entirely sure where this password must have been set, but I'm guessing I, at some point, encrypted the hard drive on the first time I installed Ubuntu... when Ubuntu installed the `TPM [enabled]` was locking me out.... So you really fixed this for me +1

Comment: @AndrewBrockman I'm glad it's working! +1 to your question too. I'm not sure why it was down voted in the first place. The mission of this place is to solve problems not to down vote them. Especially without a comment as to why.

Comment: The mokmanager is for UEFI Secure Boot keys. Ubuntu cannot certify or provide key for proprietary drivers. You must have nVidia or proprietary video of some sort or a proprietary Wi-Fi chip/card. A user can set a key for Secure boot if he is sure the proprietary driver is safe or if he builds a driver himself.

Comment: @oldfred, that's interesting to know and helpful for me to work out how exactly your suggestions got this baby fired up properly. Many thanks to all of you, life savers...

Comment: @oldfred, I think your suggestion will help me fix the wifi card, I do as you predicted have an Nvidia quadro rtx of some sort, but this works as demonstrated by nvidia-smi, the wifi card will now be debugged: I've made an honorable mention in my edit 2 to give due gratitude my friend