# Issues with Keyboard not working when booted

Tags: keyboard, bios

first time asking a question to the community, I've searched for my issue and although the information I find and solutions I try are close I'm still having problems. The laptop had a corporate build of Windows 10 on it before I blew it all away from a USB stick; I wonder if this is where I have made a grave error and I've missed something critical

I am a relatively new user of Ubuntu recent versions but have dabbled over the years to build some home media servers, proxies, web servers, etc.

**Background:**
I acquired a Microsoft Surface Laptop from a Company closure auction that has unfortunately succumbed to the terrible circumstances the COVID-19 pandemic has pressed upon the world.

I bought it to use as a nice, light, and quick device that I can take around wherever I may go and to have a bit of fun with as required. The portability side of things is where I am struggling.

I built the laptop and I noticed straight away the keyboard would not work. Thinking this was an OS issue after I read some issues people had after updating I did another update to bring things bang up to date. However, I still have no local keyboard functionality. The facts:

**Hardware:**

- I CAN plug in a USB keyboard and everything is fine, but it's not very portable.
- Nothing over standard.
- Intel Core i5
- 8GB RAM

**Software & OS:**

- no additional software installed other than OS, the salient points I think will be:

  - Ubuntu 19.10
  - GNOME: 3.34.2
  - 64-bit
  - 256GB SSD

**Fault Manifestation & observations:**

- The laptop boots as you would expect, get's all the way to the login screen and then the
  keyboard stops working
- On-Screen Keyboard is fully functional
- Touchscreen not operational, however, I suspect this may simply be a driver issue or
  something configuration related; not critical
- The Local keyboard functions as you would expect for absolutely everything else. For example
  in BIOS set up, changing boot sequence, etc.
- Local trackpad mouse is operational at all times
- Function ("Fn") key illuminates and goes out on keypress as expected
- I can force a shutdown by pressing the power key for a few seconds, so this at least tells
  me the hardware is good and we may have a BIOS / Security issue?

**Troubleshooting completed:**
Before going into this in some detail I've mentioned that the laptop had W10 on it before I got my hands on it and I simply created a USB boot image and blew away all the partitions and installed Ubuntu onto (what I thought) was a fresh disk and config.

- Looking through the BIOS I can see a setting for TPM (Trusted Platform Module). I have tried
  every possible combination with this including having secure boot Off, Microsoft Only and
  Microsoft with 3rd party CA. If I get it wrong to a point then it will just say it ran into an
  issue and won't boot at all. I then revert it to the last combo that I could get Ubuntu to
  boot but of course, the keyboard will not work
- I have tried sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all

To conclude I think this issue is a result of the previous company implementing some physical security to prevent data loss, and, ironically to probably prevent someone like me trying to do what I am!

I'd like to stick to Ubuntu as it suits the use case I have perfectly, I could buy and install a fresh copy of Windows 10 but I'm relatively sure the same issue will persist if it's not an enterprise installation where it can connect to local policy servers, etc.

**TL;DR - Bought a laptop from a corporation, blitzed it with Ubuntu, the keyboard doesn't work but everything else does.**

Comment: Great summary.  What surface do you have.  I have one also and it runs well.  If you removed the W10 then you should be able to turn off security.  If all else works then I think the issue is NOT Bios or underlying mistakes you may have made.  Proabably just a driver issue.  If the keyboard works till login then what is happening is this.  It gets switched off by a blacklist.  When the GUI loads it decides to use a different driver and off it goes. Try looking for additional drivers.

Comment: It’s just a surface laptop, I can get more details from the system tomorrow where needed. I think its a gen 3.

Thank you. I tried to be clear as possible but of course I missed in my summary that I had stumbled across the blacklist hint and followed some breadcrumbs that led me to the below link. I completed the command in step 2 but still no joy. My experience or lack there of is now showing so I am sure I need to do more. I’ll have a look at other drivers tomorrow. 

Thanks for the reply.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/851975/a-tpm-error-7-occurred-attempting-to-read-a-pcr-value

Comment: @walttheboss - Still trying to figure this out. Interestingly i do not have a listing on the left hand side for "Keyboard" when in the Settings > Devices menu. This may support your blacklist theory even more.

I cannot figure out how to find and install other drivers, any help here is very much appreciated. As would any hints around manipulating the blacklist entries..

Answer (score 0):

to close this off i now have this working. I followed this thread on Reddit:

https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup

The step i missed all along was to install and confirm the certificate to allow this to work with systems that support Secure boot:

https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup